# igraph to_undirected() method analogy in NetworkX

Tags: python, igraph, networkx, undirected-graph

In igraph I found two different methods for converting graph to undirected graph: 
The first is `to_undirected` which simply 'Converts a directed graph to undirected.' and the second is `as_undirected` which invokes `to_undirected` on the copy.

In NetworkX I found only single method `to_undirected` which simply create undirected deep copy of the graph. The problem is that I really can't found method similar to the first one in igraph. Is there any solution to transform graph without creating copy using NetworkX?

Answer (score 2):

As you state, `networkx.to_undirected` creates a deep copy of the graph. This means that it copies the edge, node, and graph attribute dictionaries. To create an undirected shallow copy of a digraph `g`, one can write:

```
g = networkx.Graph(g)
```

This is still a copy, but a shallow one in which the attribute dictionaries are not deep copied.

It does not appear that a method exists to convert a `DiGraph` to a `Graph` *in-place*. Doing as much would mean changing the type of the object -- it's likely cleaner to simply do a shallow copy, and not that much more expensive.